# Setting up an Express JS app

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using express for my application.  Currently, when I run the server and open the browser to my local host, the index page that I want to do a GET request to is displayed.  The problem is, there's supposed to be an image on the page, and it isn't displaying

GET http://localhost:3000/public/img/ssi.png 404 (Not Found)

I'm getting a 404 not found, I'm confused because I know in my html, the file path to that image is correct

```
    <a href="index.html"><img src="../public/img/ssi.png"></a>
```

this is my file structure:

- express_app

  - node_modules
  - public

    - css
    - img

      - ssi.png
    - js
  - router
  - views

    - index.html

below is my server code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('public', __dirname + '/public');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.render('index.html');
     });
app.get('/about',function(req,res){
        res.render('about.html');
    });

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("We have started our server on port 3000");
});
```

Somebody, anybody, please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your don't need to put relative paths in your `html` file. Just the path starting from the `public` folder of your project.

You should also use the static files api from express in order to serve static files (usually inside the `public` folder).
Here is how you do it:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

So, in your example, it should be accessible using `<img src="img/ssi.png">`